# How to map NUM keys?

Tags: key-bindings

I am using Vim version 7.4 from 2012-Dez-06 of Ubuntu 16.04, and I use PuTTY 0.67 on W10. I want to map the keys of the NUM pad in `.vimrc`. This doesn't work:

```
map <k1> COMMAND
map k1 COMMAND
map <C-k1> COMMAND
map <S-k1> COMMAND
map *keypad-1* COMMAND
map keypad-1 COMMAND
```

If I do for example:

```
map 1 dd
```

it works and the line is deleted if I hit `1`.

If I hit in vi the NUM buttons I get q, r, s, t ... If I map `q` to a command only the normal `q` button will execute the command but not `1` on the NUM pad.
My `.vimrc` is:

```
# cat ~/.vimrc
syntax on
set t_Co=256
colorscheme elflord
if &diff
    colorscheme apprentice
endif
```

The h keycodes (Thanks to Ashok) is:

```
Notation        Bedeutung                   Äquivalent  Dezimale/r Wert/e   ~
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
<Nul>           Null                    CTRL-@    0 (gespeichert als 10) *<Nul>*
<BS>            Zeichenrückschritt      CTRL-H    8     *backspace*
<Tab>           Tabulator               CTRL-I    9     *tab* *Tab*
                                                        *linefeed*
<NL>            Zeilenvorschub          CTRL-J   10 (benutzt für <Nul>)
<FF>            Seitenvorschub          CTRL-L   12     *formfeed*
<CR>            Wagenrücklauf           CTRL-M   13     *carriage-return*
<Return>        dasselbe wie <CR>                               *<Return>*
<Enter>         dasselbe wie <CR>                               *<Enter>*
<Esc>           Fluchttaste             CTRL-[   27     *escape* *<Esc>*
<Space>         Leertaste                        32     *space*
<lt>            weniger-als             <        60     *<lt>*
<Bslash>        Backslash               \        92     *backslash* *<Bslash>*
<Bar>           vertikaler Strich       |       124     *<Bar>*
<Del>           Löschen                         127
<CSI>           Befehlsfolgeneinleiter  ALT-Esc 155     *<CSI>*
<xCSI>          CSI in der GUI getippt                  *<xCSI>*

<EOL>           Zeilenende (kann <CR>, <LF> oder <CR><LF> sein, hängt ab vom
                System und 'fileformat')        *<EOL>*

<Up>            Cursor rauf                     *cursor-up* *cursor_up*
<Down>          Cursor runter                   *cursor-down* *cursor_down*
<Left>          Cursor links                    *cursor-left* *cursor_left*
<Right>         Cursor rechts                   *cursor-right* *cursor_right*
<S-Up>          Umschalttaste Cursor rauf
<S-Down>        Umschalttaste Cursor runter
<S-Left>        Umschalttaste Cursor links
<S-Right>       Umschalttaste Cursor rechts
<C-Left>        Steuerung Cursor links
<C-Right>       Steuerung Cursor rechts
<F1> - <F12>    Funktionstaste 1 bis 12         *function_key* *function-key*
<S-F1> - <S-F12> Umschalttaste Funktionstaste 1 bis 12  *<S-F1>*
<Help>          Hilfetaste
<Undo>          Undo-Taste
<Insert>        Einfügetaste
<Home>          Anfang                          *home*
<End>           Ende                            *end*
<PageUp>        Bild rauf                               *page_up* *page-up*
<PageDown>      Bild runter                             *page_down* *page-down*
<kHome>         Anfang auf dem Ziffernblock (oben links)*keypad-home*
<kEnd>          Ende auf dem Ziffernblock (unten links) *keypad-end*
                                                        *keypad-page-up*
<kPageUp>       Bild rauf auf dem Ziffernblock (oben rechts)
                                                        *keypad-page-down*
<kPageDown>     Bild runter auf dem Ziffernblock (unten rechts)
<kPlus>         + auf dem Ziffernblock                  *keypad-plus*
<kMinus>        - auf dem Ziffernblock                  *keypad-minus*
<kMultiply>     * auf dem Ziffernblock                  *keypad-multiply*
<kDivide>       / auf dem Ziffernblock                  *keypad-divide*
<kEnter>        Enter auf dem Ziffernblock              *keypad-enter*
<kPoint>        Dezimalzeichen auf dem Ziffernblock     *keypad-point*
<k0> - <k9>     0 bis 9 auf dem Ziffernblock            *keypad-0* *keypad-9*
<S-...>         Umschalttaste                   *shift* *<S-*
<C-...>         Steuerungstaste                 *control* *ctrl* *<C-*
<M-...>         Alt-Taste oder Meta-Taste       *meta* *alt* *<M-*
<A-...>         dasselbe wie <M-...>            *<A-*
<D-...>         Befehlstaste (nur Macintosh)    *<D-*
<t_xx>          Taste mit dem Eintrag »xx« in der TermCap
```

I am using Putty with ssh and the following keyboard setting:
. . .

[image]
How can I map the keys of the numeric key pad?

Comment: click on the tick if my answer helps !! Means a lot !! :D

Comment: You should use `imap` for the insert mode.

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer! Just so you know, it's allowed, and even *encouraged* to answer your own question ([link](http://vi.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)). But you should post it as an answer rather than editing it into your post. I've edited your answer, but you can see your former answer [here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/revisions/c5bf3468-d7df-4e63-bc19-5a1d9dd70e08/view-source). I would encourage you to copy and paste the answer section into a real answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default settings of PuTTY are just fine. Do not change anything in `PuTTY-> Terminal -> Keyboard` (see above) or disable in `PuTTY-> Terminal -> Features` anything:

[image]

You can map in vi the NUM keys in the following way:

```
inoremap <Esc>Oq 1
inoremap <Esc>Or 2
inoremap <Esc>Os 3
inoremap <Esc>Ot 4
inoremap <Esc>Ou 5
inoremap <Esc>Ov 6
inoremap <Esc>Ow 7
inoremap <Esc>Ox 8
inoremap <Esc>Oy 9
inoremap <Esc>Op 0
inoremap <Esc>On .
inoremap <Esc>OQ /
inoremap <Esc>OR *
inoremap <Esc>Ol +
inoremap <Esc>OS -
inoremap <Esc>OM <Enter>
```

This setting is an example for using the NUM key as they should be. Of course you can change the mappings as usual.

Comment: I am glad that you could solve your problem. Nice job @musbach. Sorry my help couldnt solve, but it taught me a lot about that topic. Applause to your persistence !

Answer (score 4):

The keypad identifiers have a k* prefix.
Like mapping control + numkey 1 to :NerdTree would be

```
Map <C-k1> :NerdTree<CR>
```

AFAIK these mappings wont work when the NumLock is off.

also `:h keycodes` in vim shows a lot more of these keybindings.

EDIT : OP uses PuTTY for ssh-ing into vim. PuTTY has numkeys disabled by default which is the reason why it shows alphabets instead of numericals.

to solve this : PuTTY settings -> Terminal -> Features->put a check mark on "Disable application keypad mode". -> sessions -> save !!

Comment: Thank for the hint: `:h keycodes` tells me that I have to use <k1> (without `C-`) but is doesn't work. It seems that `k1` is already mapped and I cannot remap the button.

Comment: What do u mean 'k1 is already mapped '?? And any combination (like ctrl, shift, alt) can be used with k* to invoke a command.

Comment: The NUM 1 is already mapped by a command which duplicates the lines. If I want to map `k1` to e.g. `dd` it doesn't work and the former command is executed.

Comment: Then use k2  or try S-k1 or C-k1

Comment: No way. Always th same.

Comment: T_T , can u link ur .vimrc ?

Comment: I added my .vimrc in the question. I tested the mapping on the commandline in vi.

Comment: Mind you, plain vi doesnt use vimrc...... Also numkeys depend on terminal emulator as well

Comment: I tried vi and vim but there is not difference. But the terminal imulation is a good point. I am using PuTTy with ssh. See above for the PuTTY keyboard settings.

Comment: PuTTY settings -> Terminal -> Features......put a check mark on "Disable application keypad mode". -> sessions -> save !! :D

Comment: I tried "Disable application keypad mode" but it didn't work. I get then the arrow keys on the NUM keypad and I cannot map them. Here could be an explanation: [VIM-Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/PuTTY_numeric_keypad_mappings) Maybe an addressing of the key with `<Esc>Oq` for `1` could work in `application mode`. Since I am off my computer for the week I'll test on my return.